# Issues with requestValidationMode="2.0" and validateRequest="false"

Tags: iis, c#-4.0, windows-server-2008-r2

I've been looking at this issue for quite a while now.

Basicly what the issue is that IIS 7.5 and IIS Express both ignore the following two lines:
    
    
I've googled and searched here on stackoverflow and most just suggest adding those two lines, but it does not matter what I do(reboot server, create a new app pool) it does not work.

Anyone got any ideas to why this happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you also need to add ValidateInput(false) to your action if you are dealing with MVC.

or add deriective on the page if you are working on web forms